# is the notion of a Table required at all in Azure Table service?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am working with azure table services. What I would like to ask is whether the Azure internals care about the notion of *Table* at all?

Making things fast largely depend on partition key and row key. Tables do not look like containers or Grouping of entities because there is no limit on number of tables you can create. The total storage size is tied to my storage account.

So is Table just a notion to help people transition from RDBMS land or do they serve a purpose internally? Can I do applications with a single table design without worrying about performance? After all, if table is a just a tag then I may as well include as part of partition key.

**EDIT**

To give an example, Table partition keys look very much like Cassandra rows and Table rows are like Cassandra columns. It is okay to treat the Storage as a big bucket of key(RowKey)-value pairs. Partition keys are sharding mechanism. Then table just comes across as a "labeling" notion.

Comment: How is a table not a container? I'm not following you.

Comment: Azure Table Storage is a very different design than a traditional RDBMS like SQL. You could design an app to just use a single table if you're not working w/ a bunch of relational data. Performance with tables becomes a problem if you can't do lookups based on the partition and row key. Julie has nice [Azure Table Storage writeup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796231.aspx) you might be interested in reading.

Answer (score 2):

You can have all your entities in a single azure table storage and get optimum performance by thoughtfully choosing a right Partition Key and Row Key combination, but IMHO it is any time better to have related entities each in a separate table as that would be easy manageable ( from a developer perspective) . you know what part of you application is hitting which table.

You may want to view this recorded session which discusses best practices and internals.
[Windows Azure Storage: What’s Coming, Best Practices, and Internals](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-541)

Comment: Thanks, I have read that blog plus whatever else I could find. I have also updated the question with more details. The big point is that table is only required _from_developer_perspective_ . if some developer is comfortable with Azure table storage being a big bucket of key-value pairs partitioned by PK for performance then Table is just a labeling and nothing else.

Comment: you are right that is a developer convenience. What determines the performance is thoughtfully chosen Partition key, so that infrastructure could load balance you partitions in case a partition is becoming hot.here is one more video link http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/SVC09

Answer (score 0):

You can think the union of a Table name and a Partition Key as being a unit of performance.

Youre probably on the thought mindset that will re-invent [FatEntities.](https://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/wiki/FatEntities)  developed by Lokad.

The concept of a "Table" has many restrictions and issues.  For example if you have a large table with 100,000 entries in a partition, then you can't easily jump to entry 99,001 without iterating through each of the entries.  Going backwards is impossible (you cant start at the last entry and go backwards)

Comment: I do not think so and my argument is - you can grow the number of tables to anything you like. Also, your example is not correct. With right partition key and row key, I can go anywhere in my storage area. Like, I said, I can do single table design w/o compromising performance. The notion of "Table" is just to put people at ease.